# How do I use JavaScript to load and remove content when I click on buttons on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**Please assist me with a vanilla JavaScript solution** (I'm sure there are JQuery solutions but I'm not ready for that yet - I'm currently working in vanilla JavaScript only)?

I have a basic page that I am using as a testbed for a project I've been working on. I have two buttons which, when clicked, will load HTML pages in a sub-directory. At the moment, when I click on one button, it loads the content it points to. When I click on the second button, it also loads its content but underneath the other content.

This is what I want to achieve:

1. When I click on a button (any one), the content it points to loads on the page.
2. When I click on a second button, any content that loaded initially must be removed from view and replaced by the content associated with the second button (I thought about inserting CSS classes to enable me to show and hide content).

**In other words, my desired behaviour is as follows: when I click on Button 1, Page 1 loads. Then, when I click on Button 2, Page 1 goes away and Page 2 loads.**

Here is my `<body>` HTML for my test page:

```
<body>
  <nav>
   <a href="pages/page1.html" class="menulink"> Page 1 </a>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <p>This will test if I can load a page below.</p>
    <button class="btns" id="newbtn1" name="btn">Page 1</button>
    <button class="btns" id="newbtn2" name="btn">Page 2</button>
  </section>
  <h2>Content panel</h2>
  <p>Some content should load here.</p>
  <div id="container">

  </div>

 <script src="longscripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here is the JavaScript I've written so far. It is very clunky, so apologies in advance:

```
let el1 = document.createElement('div');
let el2 = document.createElement('div');
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let btnLoad = document.getElementById('newbtn1');
let btnLoad2 = document.getElementById('newbtn2');

el1.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/page1.html" title="First page" width="800" height="500">';
el2.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/page2.html" title="Second page" width="800" height="500">';


btnLoad.addEventListener('click', function( btnFunc ) {
  console.log('Page 1');
  container.appendChild( el1 );
})

btnLoad2.addEventListener('click', function( altBtnFunc ) {
  console.log('Page 2');
  container.appendChild( el2 );
})
```

This what I need help with:

1. How do I streamline my JavaScript code to simplify it? I think I can do this using a `for` loop or something along those lines but I just can't work it out how to write this code.
2. How do I make sure that when I click on a button the second and subsequent times, any content that has already been loaded will be removed and the content associated with the second (and subsequent) button loads in its place?

There are probably very elegant and straightforward solutions but my brain is just not connecting the dots. I'd appreciate any tips or help.

Comment: To remove the element you can use [`element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid off the `el1` and `el2` parameters completely since they have no use.

```
    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    let btnLoad = document.getElementById('newbtn1');
    let btnLoad2 = document.getElementById('newbtn2');

    btnLoad.addEventListener('click', function( btnFunc ) {
      console.log('Page 1');
      container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/page1.html" title="First page" width="800" height="500">';
    })

    btnLoad2.addEventListener('click', function( altBtnFunc ) {
      console.log('Page 2');
       container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="pages/page2.html" title="Second page" width="800" height="500">';
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove page 1 before adding page two with `innerHTML`. If page 2 is already loaded and you press the button, it will just remove page 2 and place it back in again.

```
btnLoad2.addEventListener('click', function( altBtnFunc ) {
  container.innerHTML = ""; // replace container contents with nothing
  console.log('Page 2');
  container.appendChild( el2 );
})
```

Comment: Thanks although there are two buttons, one for each page I'll be loading into the main page.